# How can I display single items as a grid in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Understanding to get two items next to each other I can easily do `flexDirection: 'row'`, I'm interested in how I can render items one at a time while still maintaining a `2 by x` grid.

My end goal is to have 2 columns with 0 to n rows, and each item is currently being rendered after mapping through an array.

This looks like this:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={!showAll} contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 16 }} style={{ width: screenWidth }} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
     {info && info.map((t, i) => {
          return this.parseTidbit(t, i)
     })}
</ScrollView>
```

This generates what I'm looking for at first, which is a horizontal scroll. When the variable `showAll` is toggled, it should generate the View that parseTidbit returns in that aforementioned 2 by x grid. I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.

I've tried to brainstorm some `i % 2 === 0` rendering, but I'm stuck and could use a hand. Thanks in advance.

Update:

I'm attempting to use numColumns with FlatList, but there's an issue when you pass numColumns of null or false or 0 (when displaying horizontally). So I'm attempting to not pass numColumns at all by in/excluding it when spreading an object. This isn't really working out, not sure what my other options are:

```
let passableProps = {}
if(showAll){
  passableProps['numColumns'] = 2
}
```

then:

```
  <FlatList
        horizontal={!showAll}
        contentContainerStyle={{ paddingHorizontal: 16 }}
        style={{ width: screenWidth }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index }
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={info}
        renderItem={({item: tidbit, index: i}) => this.parseTidbit(tidbit, i) }
        {...passableProps}
/>
```

This yields *ExceptionsManager.js:82 Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.*

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: Would `<FlatList numColumns={2}... />` help you in this situation?

Comment: Maybe! I've just updated the question with an attempt/current issue. It wouldn't be as easy as your snippet due to horizontal mode not supporting numColumns.